# Variables are not coming up null during Postman call

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, postman

Setting up an Java Postman call assigning values to the variables but its shows null.

```java
        @PostMapping("/caStudents/student")
    public String generateSignedValue(@RequestBody StudentRequest studentRequest) throws Exception  
        String signedValue=studentService.getSignedValue(studentRequest);
        return signedValue;
```

My Pojo `Student` Class

```java
      public class StudentRequest {
      String user;
      Long duration ;
      public String getPublicKey() {
        return publicKey;
    }

    public void setPublicKey(String publicKey) {
        this.publicKey = publicKey;
    }

    public String getUser() {
        return user;
    }

    public void setUser(String user) {
        this.user = user;
    }

    public Long getDuration() {
        return duration;
    }

    public void setDuration(Long duration) {
        this.duration = duration;
    }
```

Postman Request

```
{"studentRequest":[{"user":"admin","duration":19336}]}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

your request body should be like this:

```
{"user":"admin","duration":19336}
```

because you are getting `StudentRequest` as `RequestBody` and it means you should send `StudentRequest` internal properties not containing `StudentRequest` it self in request ,
second problem is that your `RequestBody` contains singular object not array .

Answer (score 0):

According to what you've given us your request should actually be

```json
{
   "user": "admin",
   "duration": 19336
}
```

If you want to provide multiple student requests at once (within an array), then you're `StudenRequest` class should look somewhat like this:

```java
public class StudentRequest {
  List<StudentR>;

  // Getter and Setter or not in case you use lombok

  class StudenR {
     String user;
     Long duration ;
  }
}
```